# html select php processing question?

Tags: php, mysql, select

i have this select box that users can use to choose an option, but im stuck on how i can process it with php and insert the value in mysql:

```
<select name="vote[]">
  <option value="support">I support this</option>
  <option value="against">Im against this</option>
  <option value="dont">I want the audience to decide!</option>
```

```
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO topic (topic, founder, choice, date) VALUES('".$course."', '".$user_id."', '".$_POST['vote[]']."',NOW())");
```

Comment: That looks right to me...where's the problem?

Comment: everything is inserting right, expect the $_POST['vote[]'] for the choice field, its not inserting when i select something? :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what Ben has already said, you want to drop the brackets from the `name` attribute.

```
<select name="vote">
```

When you go to retrieve the value, just use `$_POST["vote"]`. The use of square brackets is only if you intend to have multiple fields with the same name (i.e.: allowing the user to dynamically generate fields on the fly). You don't need to use it with dropdowns across the board.

**EDIT**

Also, as your resident PHP guru, I am contractually obligated to remind you to ALWAYS escape ANY data that is inserted into a SQL query. This means vigorously using `mysql_real_escape_string()` every time. Only you can prevent forest fires, VD, and god knows what else, but you can only do it if you're escaping your SQL parameters.

Comment: Oop...seems Ben deleted his answer.

Comment: I deleted it and then undeleted it. I realized after I answered that he probably knew everything I was already saying, which he confirmed. However, you are right - I don't see a need for the brackets.

Comment: @ben thanks also, its my fault for showing a bit of the code, :)) cheers

Comment: I would just like to echo and emphasize what Matt is saying. NEVER EVER EVER trust the input from a web page, even if it is "controlled" input like a select box. ALWAYS sanitize it. Read up on SQL injection here: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: @getaway Public service announcement. Do what @Ben said. Be a good citizen and sanitize your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure to close your select tag. ;) `</select>`

Second, what you'll probably want to do is include the select tag inside a `<form>` with `method="post"` and `action="somepage.php"`.

Then when the user submits the form, they will be redirected to somepage.php. In your PHP code on somepage.php, you will have an array variable called `$_POST` which will have an entry called `vote` where you can see what element was selected in the select box. You can then use this information to change how somepage.php is processed.

Check out more information on using `$_POST` with forms [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

To then get that information in a database, you'll need to access the information in the `$_POST` variable and formulate your query string (beware of SQL injection!). Then send the query using `mysql_query()` as expected.

Comment: all the processing right, im just showing a snippet of my code, the only problem i have is when i select an option its not inserting into the database, where the coice filed is, i get an empty cell

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on your database inputs, or I'll use a HTML editor and change the value of one of those `<option>`s to `'); DROP TABLE *; --` and hit submit.

You ought to read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) so you know what you're up against here. I am sure there are other things to read apart from just the PHP guide on the matter, but I don't know of any in particular that I should link you to.